# nginx custom error page for all requests

Tags: nginx

i try to provide a custom 404 for all requests in a vhost,
Tried:

```
server {
   ...
   root /var/www;
   error_page 404 /404.html;
   location / {
     return 404;
   }
}
```

Also tried to put the file outside webroot:

```
server {
   ...
   root /var/www;
   error_page 404 /var/404.html;
   location / {
     return 404;
   }
}
```

Or

```
server {
   ...
   root /var/www;       
   location / {
     error_page 404 /var/404.html;
     return 404;
   }
}
```

With no luck ....
Any ideas?

Comment: What output are you receiving? If you're accessing `http://www.example.com`, then the `return 404;` will redirect to `http://www.example.com/404.html` and so you'll need to process that request.

Comment: Try adding `location = /404.html { internal; }` so that at least that URI is not affected by your `return` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith: sorry, does not work ...the default 404 is shown

Comment: You currently return a 404 response for all URIs **including the URI /404.html** which is why your original attempts do not work. You need to decide where to put the `404.html` file and what URI to use to refer to it and create a `location` block to reference it (as I suggested in a previous comment). If you get any of those steps wrong, you will get a 404 response (but for a different reason). So what did you do wrong?

Comment: @RichardSmith - my fault. The root folder was wrong ... everything worked, like you suggested

Answer (score 4):

like @Richard Smith commented:

```
server {
  ...
  root /var/www;     
  error_page 404 /404.html;  
  location / {     
    return 404;
  }
  location = /404.html {
    internal;
  }
}
```

Works !